# Displaying Related Records based on Selected Value From Dropdown List

Tags: ms-access

This is my data model:

[image].

Can anyone please explain, how I can make a Form in MS Access, which works in the following way:

1. There is a dropdown list from which a user selects business unit (`Business_Unit_NAM`).
2. After the selection, on the **same** form, the respective records are shown below, for example, `Service_Request_NAM`, `Service_Request_Description_NAM`, `Phases`, `Subphases`, `Status`.
3. A user can scroll through every of the created records and change the value in the fields.

A more detailed explanation would be extremely appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a form with Business_Unit dropdown (unbound) and with subform based on TBL_Star_Requests. Link this subform with dropdown control using `Link Master Fields` and `Ling Child Fields` properties. That should be enough for requested functionality. If the dropdown on the main form will be unbound, Subform Field Linker will give an error, but it will work anyway if you add field names manually. You can use the Linker if you temporarily will bound the main form to TBL_Business_Units table and bound the dropdown to Business_Unit_ID field. Remove bounding when linking done.